# Laguerre Polynomial Termination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, orthogonal-polynomials, laguerre-polynomials

I had never learned much about Laguerre polynomials before, and I am trying to understand them for the first time. If we define the Laguerre equation as:

$$xy'' + (1-x)y' + \lambda y = 0$$

Then if you solve said equation, then the recurrence relation for the coefficients is:

$$ a_{k+1} = \frac{k-\lambda}{(k+1)^2} a_k $$

Using this along with the ratio test we find:

$$ \big\vert \frac{a_{k+1}x^{k+1}}{a_kx^k} \big\vert \rightarrow \frac{\vert k-\lambda \vert}{(k+1)^2} \vert x \vert $$

And letting $k \rightarrow \infty$, we see that the radius of the convergence should be the entire real line, right? So if that's the case, then why is it important that we terminate the series and set $\lambda$ equal to a positive integer? In contrast to this, the legendre polynomials will only be well behaved at $x = \pm 1$ if the series terminates, but we don't seem to have that same limitation in this case. So why do it? I understand that sometimes the equation is defined as:

$$ xy'' + (1-x)y' + ny $$

Which would automatically make the series terminate, but it seems that this is an anticipatory definition in favor of terminating the series. So if I'm wrong about any of this, I would very much like to know, and I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your differential equation is wrong.  It should be
$$ x y'' + (1-x) y' + \lambda y = 0$$

In general, the solutions of this differential equation can be defined in terms of Kummer M and U functions:

$$ y \left( x \right) = c_1\,{{\mathrm M}\left(-\lambda,1,x \right)}+c_2 \,{{\mathrm U}\left(-\lambda,1,x\right)}$$

The Kummer M function is a solution that is analytic on the whole complex plane.
It's only if $\lambda$ is a nonnegative integer that you can get a polynomial solution, which is a Laguerre polynomial.

Comment: Oh you're right. Thanks for the correction! But do you mean that the only way to get a finite degree polynomial is by letting $\lambda$ be a positive integer?

Comment: The only polynomial solutions are when $\lambda$ is a nonnegative integer.  This is clear from your recurrence relation.  "Finite degree polynomial" is redundant: by definition, the degree of a polynomial is finite.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!